# Get specific data- attribute through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I am trying to find the data-x and data-y values of the adjacent tiles to a tile from a map that I have created, and I have only been able to return the data values from the targeted tile. How am I able to reference the specific div element that, for example, has the value of data-x clicked - 1, and then return the element that is at that location.

The HTML code for defining the custom data attributes are as follows:

```
 <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>
            <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="1" data-y="0"></div>
            <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="2" data-y="0"></div>
            <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="3" data-y="0"></div>
```

...and so on.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpzLc.png) explains what I mean more clearly, as I am trying to click on the red div and find the values of data-x and data-y of the green divs to the top, bottom, left and right of the red div.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding clicks to every element, you can add one to the parent. US ent target to get what was clicked. Than you can read the attributes. Than it is a simple querySelector with attributes to get the elements.

```js
document.getElementById("board").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
   var tile = evt.target,
       x = +tile.getAttribute("data-x"),
       y = +tile.getAttribute("data-y"),
       tileTop = document.querySelector('[data-x="'+ (x) +'"][data-y="' + (y-1) + '"]'),
       tileBot = document.querySelector('[data-x="'+ (x) +'"][data-y="' + (y+1) + '"]'),
       tileRight = document.querySelector('[data-x="'+ (x+1) +'"][data-y="' + (y) + '"]'),
       tileLeft = document.querySelector('[data-x="'+ (x-1) +'"][data-y="' + (y) + '"]');
      
  console.log(tileTop, tileBot, tileRight, tileLeft);
  
});
```

```css
.gameTile {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="1" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="2" data-y="0"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="3" data-y="0"></div>
  <br/>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="0" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="1" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="2" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="3" data-y="1"></div>
  <br/>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="0" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="1" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="2" data-y="2"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="3" data-y="2"></div>
  <br/>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="0" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="1" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="2" data-y="3"></div>
  <div class="grass gameTile" data-x="3" data-y="3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The rest of the code already exists in my program, but thank you for the querySelector answer, this fixes the problem that I was having

Comment: *"US ent target to get..."* typo?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a alternate that uses jQuery.

```js
$('.gameTile').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-x'));
  console.log($(this).attr('data-y'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grass gameTile" data-x="0" data-y="0">0</div>
<div class="grass gameTile" data-x="1" data-y="0">1</div>
<div class="grass gameTile" data-x="2" data-y="0">2</div>
<div class="grass gameTile" data-x="3" data-y="0">3</div>
```

Comment: jQuery is neither tagged nor mentioned in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Saved as an alternate option.